# Could not build wheels for turiassetstore

Tags: macos, python, open-source

I'm using Anaconda environment and trying to install `turiassetstore` library with the following cmd: 
`pip --verbose install turiassetstore==0.9.7  -i https://pypi.apple.com/simple` \

But I get the following error trace, any idea what is the problem? (MacOS with M2 chip)

````
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.apple.com/simple
Collecting turiassetstore==0.9.7
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/turiassetstore/0.9.7/turiassetstore-0.9.7.tar.gz (31 kB)
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info
  writing /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-_kh_3ral/turiassetstore.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  /Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
  !!

          ********************************************************************************
          Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/70/8e/0e2d847013cb52cd35b38c009bb167a1a26b2ce6cd6965bf26b47bc0bf44/requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting requests-toolbelt (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/3f/51/d4db610ef29373b879047326cbf6fa98b6c1969d6f6dc423279de2b1be2c/requests_toolbelt-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting python-ldap (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached python_ldap-3.4.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
Collecting boto3 (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/5a/dc/129eb802bc77fd889d587d86295c0df41cd7fea3a13e46e097f19c72b955/boto3-1.28.81-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
Collecting PyYAML (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached PyYAML-6.0.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
Collecting recertifi (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/recertifi/1.2.0/recertifi-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting appleconnect_utils (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached appleconnect_utils-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cvml-ssl>=1.0.2 (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached cvml_ssl-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting flock (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached flock-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting retry (from turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/4b/0d/53aea75710af4528a25ed6837d71d117602b01946b307a3912cb3cfcbcba/retry-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.81 (from boto3->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/cd/12/8550b63ce85f15ff4f545d7941da33b1a81bf19bb9f8e46fdde75935b226/botocore-1.31.81-py3-none-any.whl (11.3 MB)
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/31/b4/b9b800c45527aadd64d5b442f9b932b00648617eb5d63d2c7a6587b7cafc/jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 (from boto3->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/5a/4b/fec9ce18f8874a96c5061422625ba86c3ee1e6587ccd92ff9f5bf7bd91b2/s3transfer-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting pyasn1>=0.3.7 (from python-ldap->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/14/e5/b56a725cbde139aa960c26a1a3ca4d4af437282e20b5314ee6a3501e7dfc/pyasn1-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.1.5 (from python-ldap->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/cd/8e/bea464350e1b8c6ed0da3a312659cb648804a08af6cacc6435867f74f8bd/pyasn1_modules-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/16/ea/a9e284aa38cccea06b7056d4cbc7adf37670b1f8a668a312864abf1ff7c6/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (119 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/fc/34/3030de6f1370931b9dbb4dad48f6ab1015ab1d32447850b9fc94e60097be/idna-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/d2/b2/b157855192a68541a91ba7b2bbcb91f1b4faa51f8bae38d8005c034be524/urllib3-2.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (124 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/4c/dd/2234eab22353ffc7d94e8d13177aaa050113286e93e7b40eae01fbf7c3d9/certifi-2023.7.22-py3-none-any.whl (158 kB)
Collecting decorator>=3.4.2 (from retry->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/d5/50/83c593b07763e1161326b3b8c6686f0f4b0f24d5526546bee538c89837d6/decorator-5.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting py<2.0.0,>=1.4.26 (from retry->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/f6/f0/10642828a8dfb741e5f3fbaac830550a518a775c7fff6f04a007259b0548/py-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.81->boto3->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/36/7a/87837f39d0296e723bb9b62bbb257d0355c7f6128853c78955f57342a56d/python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/b0/53/aa91e163dcfd1e5b82d8a890ecf13314e3e149c05270cc644581f77f17fd/urllib3-1.26.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (143 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.32.0,>=1.31.81->boto3->turiassetstore==0.9.7)
  Using cached https://pypi.apple.com/packages/packages/d9/5a/e7c31adbe875f2abbb91bd84cf2dc52d792b5a01506781dbcf25c91daf11/six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: turiassetstore
  Running command python setup.py bdist_wheel
  /Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
  !!

          ********************************************************************************
          Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
      setuptools.setup(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 106, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 79, in _install_setup_requires
      _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 84, in _fetch_build_eggs
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 907, in fetch_build_eggs
      return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
      resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
      dist = self._resolve_dist(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 865, in _resolve_dist
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1147, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 101, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
      wheel.install_as_egg(dist_location)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 117, in install_as_egg
      self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 125, in _install_as_egg
      self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 171, in _convert_metadata
      os.rename(dist_info, egg_info)
  OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/.eggs/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3.8-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/charset_normalizer-3.3.2.dist-info' -> '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/.eggs/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3.8-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/EGG-INFO'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/bin/python -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-u6zrgtis
  cwd: /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/
  Building wheel for turiassetstore (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for turiassetstore
  Running setup.py clean for turiassetstore
  Running command python setup.py clean
  /Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
  !!

          ********************************************************************************
          Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
          If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
          ********************************************************************************

  !!
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
      setuptools.setup(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 106, in setup
      _install_setup_requires(attrs)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 79, in _install_setup_requires
      _fetch_build_eggs(dist)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 84, in _fetch_build_eggs
      dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 907, in fetch_build_eggs
      return _fetch_build_eggs(self, requires)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 38, in _fetch_build_eggs
      resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
      dist = self._resolve_dist(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 865, in _resolve_dist
      dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in best_match
      return self.obtain(req, installer)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1147, in obtain
      return installer(requirement)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 101, in _fetch_build_egg_no_warn
      wheel.install_as_egg(dist_location)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 117, in install_as_egg
      self._install_as_egg(destination_eggdir, zf)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 125, in _install_as_egg
      self._convert_metadata(zf, destination_eggdir, dist_info, egg_info)
    File "/Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/wheel.py", line 171, in _convert_metadata
      os.rename(dist_info, egg_info)
  OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/.eggs/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3.8-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/charset_normalizer-3.3.2.dist-info' -> '/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/.eggs/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3.8-macosx-11.1-arm64.egg/EGG-INFO'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /Users/sal/anaconda3/envs/de-env/bin/python -u -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize
  
  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)
  
  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__
  
  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"
  
  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'/private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c/setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' clean --all
  cwd: /private/var/folders/8t/1qgpbn815wv0h0pk6x5dsc5r0000gn/T/pip-install-of7cacx8/turiassetstore_306bf03e297840d18d951677d5f5b15c
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for turiassetstore
Failed to build turiassetstore
ERROR: Could not build wheels for turiassetstore, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using pip, you might want to try `pip --verbose install  --use-pep517 turiassetstore==0.9.7  -i htt…` and then post an update.